# Locationing prob, i dont get any longitude and latitude from background location service

Tags: android, android-location

I made a background service that should be get latitude and longitude but it for some reason not working properly:

```
public class BackgroundLocationService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = "Location Service";

private LocationManager locManager;
private LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
public static Context context;

private String latitude;
private String longitude;

Messenger messenger;
Timer t = new Timer();

public BackgroundLocationService() {
    super("backgroundLocationService");

    locManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationProviderInit();
}

private void locationProviderInit() {

    boolean gps_enabled;
    boolean network_enabled;

    gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (gps_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);

    }
    if (network_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    messenger = (Messenger) intent.getExtras().get("handler");

    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            locationProviderInit();

            if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Lat and Long are: "+latitude+" - "+longitude);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Lat and Long are null");
            }
        }
    }, 0, 7000);

}



class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
            longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
            latitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
}
```

MyLog cat:

```
01-31 15:26:54.639: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:26:58.057: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:01.643: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:05.057: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:08.639: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:12.065: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:15.643: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:19.053: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:22.639: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:26.057: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:29.643: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:33.061: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:36.639: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
01-31 15:27:40.061: I/Location Service(2347): Lat and Long are null
```

And after some time like 3-5 minutes it gets the location:

```
01-31 15:34:48.404: I/Location Service(2417): Lat and Long are: 47.479290815904015 - 19.086711048181996
01-31 15:34:55.408: I/Location Service(2417): Lat and Long are: 47.479290815904015 - 19.086711048181996
01-31 15:35:02.404: I/Location Service(2417): Lat and Long are: 47.479290815904015 - 19.086711048181996
01-31 15:35:09.400: I/Location Service(2417): Lat and Long are: 47.479290815904015 - 19.086711048181996
01-31 15:35:16.400: I/Location Service(2417): Lat and Long are: 47.479290815904015 - 19.086711048181996
01-31 15:35:23.400: I/Location Service(2417): Lat and Long are: 47.479290815904015 - 19.086711048181996
```

How can i make this faster? I dont want to wait 5 minutes before i got the locations. There is active internet connection it shouldn't be spam me for minutes with null locations.
Locationing is a mistery for me, it never do the thing for me i want, and always surprise me with randomness. I built it many ways and i just cannot make a nicely woking code.

Please help, what should i change?

Comment: have you test it on a device - my experience that I made was, that the emulator is slower than a snail.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `getLastKnownLocation`?

Comment: IMHO everybody should take advantage of it in most cases... Take a look to this article: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html